# Why are two different UIToolbars, defaulting to different styles?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitoolbar

Consider the following two toolbars that are in the same project of mine:

[image]
[image]

Notice that these toolbars look different?  The problem is that they were both created by dragging and dropping them into IB, and I didn't change any of there associated properties.  All that I did change was adding the flex controller, and change the text on the initial `UIButtonBarItem`.  Other than that, these Toolbars have not been modified and, furthermore, I've verified that their properties are exactly the same in the Attribute inspector.

How or why are they different?  Furthermore, how can I get the first, bluish `UIToolbar` to look like the grey one since the available `Black Opaque` and `Black Translucent` styles look nothing like the grey one?

Am I missing something?  This doesn't make any since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why this is happening but I'm a bit clueless on how to change this.  See [this, new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805521/oops-i-didnt-check-the-targeted-for-ipad-option-when-creating-a-uiviewcontro) regarding a fix for this issue.

These Toolbars are changed due to internal Xib settings that are specified when the Xib is created.  In the first example, when I created the `UIViewController` I must have unchecked the *Target for iPad* check box, even this is for an iPad project.

[image: When the Targe for iPad option is not checked, Toolbars (and presumedly other UIView objects) will be styled differently.]

This changed the default size of the initial UIView that was in the Nib.  I always cut off the statusbar and set the view to be freeform in sizing as soon as I create a UIView within a Xib file, so I can never tell by looking at my views whether they were targeted for the iPad or not.

When I created the second `UIViewController` object, I checked the *Targeted for iPad* option.  Now, my toolbar is styled with a grey tone.

The lesson learned is obvious-- if you want consistency in the default style of your objects that you pull from the IB Toolbox, be sure to create your `UIViewControllers`, specifically targeted for the iOS device.  If you've made the same mistake that I have, follow the linked question above for how to revert your UIViewController and Xib file to the other style of View Controller.